# Does the Windows XP bootloader (NTLDR) heed kernel import declarations?

Tags: windows, kernel, windows-xp, bootloader, portable-executable

I wonder whether the Windows XP bootloader (`ntldr`) actually makes use of the Windows kernel (`ntoskrnl.exe`) import declarations?

`ntoskrnl.exe` has following imported modules: `BOOTVID.dll`, `HAL.dll` and `KDCOM.dll`. So these three modules are the first ones to be loaded. Imagine that the kernel has another module declared as imported. Will that cause `ntldr` to also load it? Or does `ntldr` merely know that it should load these four modules and there is no way to change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happens, I found answer myself. And had it confirmed at [ntdev](http://www.osronline.com/cf.cfm?PageURL=showlists.CFM?list=NTDEV) mailing list.

`ntldr` indeed loads only four files mentioned in the question and doesn't use any import declarations.

You can actually check this by creating a stub kernel (that imports something from the actual kernel) and using following `boot.ini` options (you will get list of loaded modules in the `%SystemRoot%\ntbtlog.txt` file):

```
/bootlog /kernel=stubkrnl.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to ask this question in [ntdev](http://www.osronline.com/cf.cfm?PageURL=showlists.CFM?list=NTDEV) mailing list. 
To be answered you better explain why you need this information and what are you trying to do. I can assure that on this list you will find people capable to answer on this, can't assure however that you will be answered. They are a bit touchy about "hack smelling".

Comment: Ilya, thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction!